# Should I replant or leave bent leaves on my aloe plant?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, aloe, repair

I tied a string to try and help the leaves gain strength again, all but one leaf are up on their own.

[image: tied]

[image: untied]

Answer (score 2):

The likely cause of the leaf problem you have is environmental, that is, the care it's receiving. First, I suspect this plant is not receiving sufficient daylight and probably sunlight - they really need 5 or 6 hours of sun a day, which can be difficult if you're in the northern hemisphere, as it's winter. The second problem might be insufficient water, evidenced by the crispy, brown tips to some of the leaves; lack of turgidity in the leaves can also be a result of underwatering, but watering needs to be done carefully, because overwatering can also caused problems.

Shallow plant pots can cause this problem - your pot doesn't look shallow, but it may be that the plant has run out of root room and its time for a pot one size larger - turn it out of its pot if you suspect that's possible to see whether its just a mass of packed, solid roots. If it is, it needs a bigger pot. Further info regarding floppy leaves here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/aloe-vera/fixing-a-droopy-aloe-plant.htm

Answer (score 1):

When that happens to me I usually put the leaf to use. Rather than stressing the plant into putting more energy into that damaged leaf to fix it

Comment: Hi there, can you provide more detail on how to put the leaf to use or propagate it?